# How to get big icons on QFileDialog?

Tags: css, qt, icons, qfiledialog, file-icons

I'm working on a Qt UI that will run on a touchscreen. At some point it will be useful to select files, in (probably) a QFileDialog.
But little icons on a QFileDialog leads to a terrible touch-user experience, I'd like them to be bigger, so the user doesn't get crazy trying to navigate in the filesystem.
Actually, I'm searching documentation to see if there is a way through css, but haven't seen yet which target/propery to use.

Answer (score 0):

Given the doc of [QFileDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#ViewMode-enum) class:

> QFileDialog::Detail    0   Displays an icon, a name, and details for each item in the directory.
>   QFileDialog::List  1    Displays only an icon and a name for each item in the directory.

You can't set icon size this way. I recommend you to [set a custom icon provider](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileiconprovider.html) on the `QFileDialog`.